# Is there a CSS only way to hide elements only when another element has a different class applied?

Tags: css

I am working with a filter system that I cannot control the css output tags of.

The filter outputs everything into a list and highlights the "selected" item with an "active" class tag. This is used to highlight that list item.

What I want to acheive is when everything is set as follows all items display. But as soon as one is active the rest hide using display:none.

```
<ul> 
  <li class="normal">1 Display</li>
  <li class="normal">2 Display</li>
  <li class="normal">3 Display</li>
  <li class="normal">4 Display</li>
  <li class="normal">5 Display</li>
<ul>
```

- 1 Display
- 2 Display
- 3 Display
- 4 Display
- 5 Display

Would turn to:

```
<ul> 
  <li class="normal">1 Display</li>
  <li class="normal">2 Display</li>
  <li class="normal">3 Display</li>
  <li class="normal active">4 Display</li>
  <li class="normal">5 Display</li>
<ul>
```

- 4 Display

Css would be something along the line of

```
li:not(.active){
  display:none; 
}
```

But this should only come into effect once something is active but with a variable to only make it operate if .active is present.

Comment: I guess you can not add a class to the ul element when there is an active child? So you could use the ul's class to determine wheter you should hide all normal non active elements or not.

Comment: Not possible with CSS. You'd need Javascript...but adding a class to the `ul` as suggested above would be ideal.

Comment: @lucamuh thought of adding a class to the ul above, it would make things very easy. This is, unfortunately, is a limitation of what I am working with.

Answer (score 1):

Your are able to do this by using javascript.

```
var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var active= 0;
for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    if (li[i].className == 'normal active') {
        li[i].style.display = 'block';
        active = 1;
    }else{
        li[i].style.display = 'none';
    }      
}
if(active == 0){
 for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
   li[i].style.display = 'block';
 }
}
```